# SubsetSum using recursion and backtracking

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking, subset-sum

I have written an algorithm to return whether a subset of a group of numbers will sum to a given target using backtracking and recursion (returns true/false)

Ex: {5, 2, 3, 6} with Target = 8 ==> True ||
{5, 2, 3, 6} with Target = 20 ==> False

**I want to modify my algorithm so that it includes all 5's that maybe present in the set. I am having a hard time how to figure this out using backtracking and recursion. Any advice is appreciated**

Ex: {5, 2, 3, 6} with Target 8 ==>True ||
    {6, 2, 3, 5, 5} with Target 8 ==> False

I have written an algorithm that recursively includes a number and checks the sum and then omits the number from the sum but I don't know how to modify my algorithm to only pick a certain numbers and include them in the sum

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int[] ints = { 10, 1, 3, 2 };
        int target = 5;
        int start = 0;
        System.out.println(groupSum(ints, target, 0, start));
    }

    public static boolean groupSum(int[] arr, int target, int sum, int start) {
        if (sum > target) {
            return false;
        }
        if (sum == target) {
            return true;
        }
        if (start >= arr.length) {
            return false;
        }
        //choose
        sum = sum + arr[start];
        //explore
        if (groupSum(arr, target, sum, start + 1))
            return true;
        //un-choose
        sum = sum - arr[start];
        return groupSum(arr, target, sum, start + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Answer for this set =  {6, 2, 3, 5, 5} with Target 8 should be True right, why are you mentioning False then.

Comment: No beacuse if i were to use all 5's, the sum of 5 + 5 = 10, which is greater than 8.

Comment: No beacuse if i were to use all 5's, the sum of 5 + 5 = 10, which is greater than 8.

Comment: So what's the question, you need to find a subset which contains all 5 and some few numbers and if there sum is equal to target then it should return true, something like this.

Comment: Yes. Also can I make some change to my algorithm for this? Since I alredy check for all combinations.

Comment: I mean create one more method and filter out all 5's from the array, take their sum and perform target - sum and then call this method with filtered out array and new target value

Comment: Thanks. I figured there is no other way other than first summing all the 5s and then adding in the other numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196166/discussion-between-spindoctor-and-zenwraight).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force it to only look at including `5` if it sees it, and only check `= sum` at the end.  Like this:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    int[] ints = { 10, 1, 3, 2 };
    int target = 5;
    int start = 0;
    System.out.println(groupSum(ints, target, 0, start));
}

public static boolean groupSum(int[] arr, int target, int sum, int start) {
    if (sum > target) {
        return false;
    }
    // NOTE: sum == target inside of end of array check so all 5s are found.
    if (start >= arr.length) {
        return sum == target;
    }
    //choose
    sum = sum + arr[start];
    //explore
    if (groupSum(arr, target, sum, start + 1))
        return true;
    //un-choose
    // NOTE: can't unchoose 5
    if (5 == arr[start]) {
        return false;
    }
    sum = sum - arr[start];
    return groupSum(arr, target, sum, start + 1);
}
```

**Update:** Here is advice on how to solve problems like this.

1. Very clearly state what you want the function to do.
2. Very clearly state what the base case or cases are where you know the answer.
3. In the complex case, figure out how to reduce it to one or more simpler problems.

As long as you've done that, your recursive code should work.  And if you're in doubt about how to modify, start over from scratch, only copying code from before where you've noticed that it can be left alone.

So for the first step, the statement is, *We want groupSum to take an array `arr` of positive integers, a target `target`, a partial sum `sum` and an int `start` and to return whether it is possible to get the rest of the array to sum to `target` when you take a subset that has to include all 5s.*

For the second step, base cases are:

- We've already exceeded `target`, then it is `false`.
- We've reached the end of the array and are at `target`, then it is `true`.
- We've reached the end of the array and are blow `target`, then it is `false`. (I combined this with the last in the code by returning a comparison.)

For the third step, the reductions are as follows.

- If we can add the current value and make it, the answer is `true`.
- If the current value is not 5, we don't add it, and can make it, the answer is `true`.
- Otherwise it is false.

I was trying to write the code in the way that looked most like what you already had.  But to write it exactly according to this logic it would be like this:

```
public static boolean groupSumWithAll5s(int[] arr, int target, int sum, int start) {
    // Base cases
    if (sum > target) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ((start >= arr.length) && (sum == target)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (start >= arr.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // Recursive cases.
    if (groupSumWithAll5s(arr, target, sum + arr[start], start + 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if ((arr[start] != 5) && groupSumWithAll5s(arr, target, sum, start + 1)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks btilly. Can you share any advice on how to formulate recursive patterns to solve problems. I seem to be having a hard time seeing how a pattern can solve a problem. I am struggling to understand how your changes make it work. I guess i will have to trace it but it is very hard to see how to put this together.

Comment: @Spindoctor I added such advice, and showed how you would mechanically create code for this problem from that advice without taking shortcuts.

Comment: thank you very much. Appreciate your patience. Will analyze and trace and get this concept down.